# If statement running even though the expression is false

Tags: android

I'm writing some java code for an android app and for some reason, an if statement is being executed even though the expression is false.

In the code below, it should execute the if statement if `verbLength > 1` however, even though verbLength is 1, the if statement is still running. I only want it to run if it is 2 or more (I have also tried `verbLength >= 2`)

```
        // Verifies the value of verbLength by showing it in a toast, this displays "1"
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), verbLength, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (verbLength > 1) {
        // Lets me verify that this if statement is in fact running
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // The code that is being executed anyway
        TextView cardContent2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.verbText2);
        cardContent2.setText(verbContentArray[1]);
        TextView cardTitle2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.verbName2);
        cardTitle2.setText(verbTitleArray[1]);
        TextView cardPrefix2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.verbTitle2);
        cardPrefix2.setText(verbPrefix);
    }
    else{
        CardView cardView2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view2);
        cardView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

The `Toast` before the `if` statement lets me know for sure that verbLength = 1 and hasn't been changed by accident. The toast inside the if statement shows that the `if` statement has run and I haven't accidentally run the code somewhere else.

I also have another if statement afterwards, which is functionally identical except it should only run if `verbLength >=3`. This code is also being executed.

**EDIT:**

If it helps, verbLength is declared as an int earlier in the code and is given it's value through `verbLength = (R.integer.testLength);`

Comment: if `verbLength` is int the first `Toast` should  crash your app

Comment: If verbLength is an int with the value 1 then there's no way that should execute the code inside the if. 

Try setting the value of verbLength = 0 immediately before the control statement, just to show that the control statement works.

Comment: Sorry buddy but your verbLength is not int becuase if its int the Toast line will show an error because it requires a String ,and still your code is working check the dataType of verbLength

Comment: Toast accepts resource id as well which is an int.So it wont show any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it helps, verbLength is declared as an int earlier in the code and
>   is given it's value through verbLength = (R.integer.testLength);

You are not assigning to `verbLength` the declared value but its id which is probably greater than `1`. Try initializing its value with

```
verbLength = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.testLength);
```

Comment: Toast accepts resource id as well which is an int.So it wont show any error.

Comment: yes, but is it kind of difficult to find a resid with value `1` and I comment it before knowing that `verbLength` was a resource's id,   @Renjith,

Comment: This solved the issue. I made some breakpoints in the code and realised that verbLength was actually set to a very long number, which I assume is the ID. Using this code instead gave me the actual value, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

That is odd, try defining a final int and passing that in instead of verbLength and see if you can get it to work.  You could also replace 1 with a final int.  I don't think thats going to change anything, but if it does, your problem lies in how your getting verbLength and what type of variable it is

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer (but I see you don't have comment privileges).